# Differentiation and piecewise function

Tags: calculus

I have the following problem:
$$f(x) = \cases {x\ln x , x \gt 0 \cr
                 0,  x \le 0}$$

and I need to show the following:

- it is continuous at $x=0$
- is $f(x)$ differentiable at $x = 0$? Explain
- find the absolute minimum over $[0, \infty )$

For the first part, I believe I need to find the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches 0 from the left and right. 
    $$(0)\ln(0) = 0$$ and the function is undefined when $x=0$. At this point I get confused and get total brain freeze. Can someone help me out?

Comment: For the first part: Taking the limit does NOT mean just plug in 0.

Comment: For the second part: Use the definition of derivative at $x=0$. You know the one with $\lim h\to 0$.

Comment: For the third part: Think about what the function $f$ looks like, based on the properties of $f'$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To study continuity at $0:$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} x\ln x=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln x}{1/x}\underbrace{=}_{L'Hospital} \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1/x}{-1/x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0} (-x)=0,$$ from where you get that $f$ is continuous at $x=0.$ (It is clear that $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=0=f(0).) $

To study differentiability at $0:$

$$f'(0^+)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x\ln x}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \ln x=-\infty,$$ that is, $f$ has not derivative at $x=0.$

Finally, to get the minimum:

$$f'(x)=\ln x+1=0 \iff x=\frac 1e.$$

Since $f''\left(\frac 1e\right)>0$ we get that $f$ has a local minimum at $x=1/e.$ Prove that it is a global minimum.

Answer (score 1):

For continuity at zero:
We have to show that $$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=f(0)$$
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}x\ln(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=0=f(0)$.

Also $=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}0=0=f(0)$.

There it is continuous at 0.

Comment: You are wrong about that your function is undefined at 0. $f(0)=0$

Answer (score 1):

Although the function may be undefined at $x=0$, approaching from the left you can use squeeze/sandwhich theorem to say the the limit of the function is $0$ and thus the limits of both the left and right sides of the equation are equal.

Therefore the function is continuous. From there you can differentiate and find the minimum value by diffrentiating $x\log x$.

Comment: @Behaviour No, it had been much longer. And you have right in the actual case, but you haven't from the viewpoint, that a big part of people writing here are functionally illiterate, and you can't make the reviewers task to fix all of them. We are not a gigantic spellchecker machine.